# Using Observable Boolean to set visibility of an android view

Tags: android, android-view, android-databinding

This is regarding something quite trivial that I have been fighting over in a code review. The scenario is such. There is a data binding layout:`some_layout.xml`, backed by a `ViewModel`.

[contents of`some_layout.xml` ]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
        <variable name="viewModel" type="some.long.package.name.SomeViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <!-- Other stuffs -->

    <TextView
        <!-- Other parameters-->>
        android:visibility="@{viewModel.someObservableBool?View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
    />
</layout>
```

The requirement, is such I want the `TextView` to be `View.GONE` (and not `View.INVISIBLE`), when the Boolean is `false`. The reviewer of my code is insistent of the fact,I should use the Boolean value directly instead of the ternary operator for `android:visibility`[`android:visibility="@{viewModel.someObservableBool}"`]

Now my understanding is that because of the implicit conversion of the truth values to int will cause the view to be `Visible`/`Invisible` but not `Gone`. As the `attrs.xml` definition states the following.

```
<!-- Controls the initial visibility of the view.  -->
<attr name="visibility">
    <!-- Visible on screen; the default value. -->
    <enum name="visible" value="0" />
    <!-- Not displayed, but taken into account during layout (space is left for it). -->
    <enum name="invisible" value="1" />
    <!-- Completely hidden, as if the view had not been added. -->
    <enum name="gone" value="2" />
</attr>
```

Is my understanding incorrect ?

Comment: Why don't you ask the reviewer to clarify - thats the point of the review - to have an open dialog. Personally xml should have no presentation logic, the contract IMO is that the ViewModel` should be a 1:1 representation of view state, which in this case it isn't.

Comment: I absolutely agree, but for some unfortunate reason this is one of those review iterations where every argument, ends at the point - "Please do this, because this is a convention we all agreed upon, and if you think it is so terrible please raise your concern in the appropriate room".  I am just concerned if my understanding of the Bool to int conversion is correct.

Comment: Sure - I'd argue the convension is also open for discussion and should not be set in stone, over time best practices can change/update.  For this particular issue you should ask the reviwer for reference where this convension has been used with view states of `View.GONE` and `View.VISIBLE`.  To me I'd provde the `int` value to the view directly, rather than a `boolean` as visibility, as you've pointed out is tri-state.

Comment: Thanks for your reply that sounds so much more sane! I had initially created an `enum` to reflect the visibility state (considering a more readable form), instead of passing a raw int. But I had to step down, as concerns were raised - that such a thing is a terrible over-complication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no implicit type conversion in java, and integer values are not interpreted as booleans - it means that if you write

```
 <TextView
        <!-- Other parameters-->>
        android:visibility="@{viewModel.someObservableBool}"
    />
```

it just will not compile.

But if you add

```
@BindingConversion
fun booleanToVisibility(value: Boolean?) = if (value == true)View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
```

it should work. You can check related docs [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters)

Comment: Oh, but  `android:visibility="@{viewModel.someObservableBool}"` this does compile without an error from the `DataBinding` compiler . I am not exactly sure of the reasoning for that, looks like there are some conversions happening in the generated binding code. BTW, Thanks for replying !

Comment: can you past compile stacktrace?

Comment: I stand corrected, there is an existing generic `BindingAdapter` [`@BindingAdapter("android:visibility")
 fun TextView.setVisibility(b: Boolean) = if (b) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE `]implemented in a common module. The generated data binding code is making a call to that with the `boolean` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with below approach provided the instance if `viewModel` and `View` are imported in XML

```
<TextView
    android:visibility="@{(viewModel.someObservableBool())? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />
```

No need to import the Observable variable since the viewModel is already available in this context.

Answer (score -1):

I am using it something like this way for email validation, something for visibility by [ObservableBoolean](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableBoolean):

XML:

```
<data>

    <import type="android.view.View" />

    <variable
        name="isProperEmail"
        type="androidx.databinding.ObservableBoolean" />
</data>

<!--    your other code here-->

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            ---------
            ---------
            android:visibility="@{isProperEmail ?View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />
```

and using it in class:

```
private val isProperEmail = ObservableBoolean(false)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    -------------

    binding.isProperEmail = isProperEmail
}
```

Now, whenever you make changes to the value of this class' `isProperEmail` variable, then it will be changed and affected to the XML/Layout.